# mkdir -p over SSH bash

Tags: ssh, mkdir

I have a small test script as follows;

```
TESTDIR="$HOSTNAME"
ssh user@server.com "\$TESTDIR"
mkdir -p ~/$TESTDIR/test
exit
```

the output with `bash -x` is;

```
+ TESTDIR=ndx
+ ssh user@server.com '$TESTDIR'
+ mkdir -p /home/user/ndx/test
+ exit
```

Yet on the remote server, no directory exists?

Comment: you're running mkdir/exit LOCALLY. they're not sent over the ssh link, and the ssh command will BLOCK until the remote shell is closed. by the time the mkdir command is reached, ssh has exited and the link is closed. `ssh ... -c 'command; to -execute; remotely'` is what you want.

Comment: may I ask for an example please?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The last argument of `ssh` is *command* you want to execute on the remote host:

```
TESTDIR="$HOSTNAME"
ssh user@server.com "mkdir -p ~/$TESTDIR/test"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a pem file to ssh as authentication use the following

```
ssh -i your-key.pem user@ip_addr "mkdir -p /your_dir_name/test"
```